# "unfair-play" tag usage

Tags: discussion, tags

The [unfair-play](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unfair-play) has been introduced. Is this appropriate for use on Sports SE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept of "unfair play" is quite subjective to the community as a whole.

What is unfair? For example, some call flopping in basketball [unfair](http://sports.espn.go.com/nba/news/story?id=4694898) while others call it [commonplace](http://www.slamonline.com/online/nba/2013/05/lebron-james-says-flopping-can-be-an-effective-strategy/). As a result, [fines](http://sports.espn.go.com/nba/news/story?id=3416579) have been instituted to mitigate such occurrences.

Hence, [officiating](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/officiating) and/or [rules](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules) cover fair/unfair play in a more objective matter while [fair-play](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fair-play) or [unfair-play](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unfair-play) introduce the possibility of opinion-basis.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not.

However, since tags age away automagically if they are not adopted and used on more than a question, I'm not too worried about it. As it is it's not currently on any questions so it will die shortly.

I'm inclined to say that it's more positive cousin [fair-play](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fair-play) is more appropriate, but that's just me.

Comment: [tag:fair-play] isn't being used either...

Comment: You need to show the reason why is it not appropriate. Agreement/disagreement can be done my voting on the question.